# MFC. Class CListCtrl. How to determine max possible column width in symbols?

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

Does MFC provides interface for getting the maximum possible width of a column of instance of the class `CListCtrl`?
If so what it is?
Thanks.

**Update:** Here is a small code snippet that shows how I am going to use the value:

```
LV_ITEM item;
item.mask = LVIF_TEXT; // state what type of info we want to get
item.iItem = pos;
item.iSubItem = col;
item.pszText  = ItemText; // as we request text for the particular item the result will be in .pszText variable
item.cchTextMax = /*here goes maxColumnWidthInSymbols*///ArrayLen ( ItemText );
// 2. Execute request
GetItem ( & item );
```

Comment: Do you mean the maximum value that you can use to set the width with `SetColumhnWidth` or something else?

Comment: @Roger Rowland  I mean the length of the text of subitem

Comment: Ok, do you need this to automatically set the column width to fit the longest item?

Comment: @Roger Rowland no, my intent is to get this value in order to allocate memory in heap for buffer

Comment: Ok, then I think you either have to keep track of it when you populate the list, or iterate all items and use `GetItemText` and find the max length.

Comment: @ Roger Rowland I added the code snippet to make my intent clear. And another possible usage: validating user input (in case if length of the string provided for a subitem is larger than ClistCtrl can display/handle - notify user)